# Order Stacked Bars Plot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rshiny

I've tried to organize by factor levels; I've tried to organize my data, but nothing is working.
I want the stacked bars to be from either 1-5 or 5-1.

Data:

```
                        Scale variable value
5  5 - Extremely valuable     Q10A 17.8%
10 5 - Extremely valuable     Q10B 18.9%
4                       4     Q10A 27.1%
9                       4     Q10B 31.4%
3                       3     Q10A 31.5%
8                       3     Q10B 32.4%
2                       2     Q10A 12.7%
7                       2     Q10B  8.8%
1     1 - No value at all     Q10A   11%
6     1 - No value at all     Q10B  8.6%
```

Code:

```
 ggplot(breakstablemelt,aes(x=variable, y=value,fill=Scale))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      coord_flip()+
      labs(title="title",
           x="Q10",
           y=NULL)
```

Organizing Data by Scale:

```
breakstablemelt=breakstablemelt[order(breakstablemelt$Scale,decreasing=T),]
```

Edit:
Factor Organization:

```
 breakstablemelt$Scale<-factor(breakstablemelt$Scale, levels=breakstable$Scale)
 breakstablemelt2=breakstablemelt %>% arrange(desc(Scale))
```

Graph output:
[unordered stacked bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxx9y.png)

Comment: Organising factor levels should usually do it - could you post the code that you tried, please?

Answer (score 1):

Removed the percent symbols at the end of the Value column, and it fixed everything.